# NoSuchMethodError with Hibernate OGM

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate-ogm

I'm working around with Hibernate OGM 5.0.0.Final with mongodb 3.2 using Spring 4, WildFly 10

This code below works fine with Object[]

```
List<Object[]> result = em.createNativeQuery("{ \"id\": \"1\" }").getResultList();
```

But if I use entity to query like this

```
List<Survey> result = em.createNativeQuery("{ \"id\": \"1\"}", Survey.class).getResultList();
```

It'll throw

```
ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.addUninitializedEntity(Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/EntityKey;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hibernate/persister/entity/EntityPersister;Lorg/hibernate/LockMode;ZLorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;)V
       at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.loadFromResultSet(OgmLoader.java:1143)
       at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.instanceNotYetLoaded(OgmLoader.java:1065)
       at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.getRow(OgmLoader.java:959)
       at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.getRowFromResultSet(OgmLoader.java:498)
       at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.doQuery(OgmLoader.java:373)
       at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(OgmLoader.java:283)
       at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.loadEntity(OgmLoader.java:201)
       at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.load(OgmLoader.java:157)
       at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.impl.OgmLoader.load(OgmLoader.java:149)
       at org.hibernate.ogm.loader.entity.impl.DynamicBatchingEntityLoaderBuilder$DynamicBatchingEntityLoader.load(DynamicBatchingEntityLoaderBuilder.java:116)
       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3991)
       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1142)
       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:167)
       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2762)
       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2741)
       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:978)
       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionDelegatorBaseImpl.get(SessionDelegatorBaseImpl.java:629)
       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1075)
       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1033)
       at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.impl.OgmEntityManager.find(OgmEntityManager.java:97)
```

Do anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Here's some of my code

Survey.java

```
@Entity
public class Survey {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String created_by;

    private String desc;

    //getter,setter
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="mongodb_persistence"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- Use Hibernate OGM provider: configuration will be transparent -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

        <class>com.ogm.entity.Survey</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="JBossAS" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="localhost" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port" value="27017" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="testdb" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.neo4j.database_path" value="target/test_data_dir" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: It seems there is an error in the Hibernate ORM version on the classpath. What are you deploying and how did you add the dependencies? Are you using the Hibernate ORM  provided by WildFly?

Comment: @ThanatManeenut, did you find a solution? If yes, I would be interested...

Comment: @camelCaseNick Actually I've change to spring-data-mongodb instead